# compile_time_purge_matching doesn't work during testing

Tags: testing, logging, elixir, elixir-mix

The following config.exs

```
config :logger,
  compile_time_purge_matching: [
    # [application: :foo],
    [module: SomeModule, level_lower_than: :error]
  ]
```

Above code works when running from shell but not when doing `mix test`

The `config.exs` is clearly parsed and i can't find that the configuration is overridden anywhere.

Comment: do you have `:logger` configuration in `test.exs`?

Comment: Nope, don't have a text.exs. As mentioned other options works, so the file is used.